Issues with the “Question Wizard”
I’ve started a new question on StackOverflow and the wizard form was shown for me.(I never saw it before)
I’ve noticed 3 issues.

When I used code icon to format block on code, it added single back-tick instead of triple back-ticks, which made all indentation and new lines inside of the block lost.
The wizard show edit text boxes, but does not shows view of actual formatting below(as normal editing form does) It  makes much harder to understand, how the html question will look like)
When I was on the last Preview page of the Wizard, I couldn’t see the submit button, but only cancel. I am not sure, what was the reason and is it reproducible, but I haven’t seen any warnings/hints explaining what to do. Fortunately I’ve noticed that I can uncheck Wizard, which made the issues away.


The reason selected was "Relates to only one specific network site" - the wizard is only available on Stack Overflow, so this question should be on Meta Stack Overflow. The site we're currently on is Meta Stack Exchange, for issues which affect multiple sites in the network.

#1 is a known issue, which was first reported quite some time ago. I'm unsure how long ago for that particular issue, but I'd expect at least a year. The Stacks Editor which SE has insisted on using in the Question Wizard has had problems, including with code, from its inception about 4.5 years ago. While some issues have been fixed, SE has declined to fix it sufficiently for it to be reasonably used, yet they have forced its use in a variety of places .

@bobble Your statement that the Stacks Editor is only available on Stack Overflow is false. The Stacks Editor is available on MSO and MSE as an opt-in editor for answers. It's also forced to be used in the SO Question Wizard, along with a couple of other places, which, includes at least some mod-only pages which are network-wide (e.g., creating a message for a user when suspending them from reviews, so at least all sites which have reviews and review suspensions).

While bug reports are quite helpful, thank you for taking the time to report them, it is strongly preferred that you submit one bug per question. Please [edit] this question to include only one of the issues you have identified and create new questions to report the other two issues. Having separate questions with the issues allows better tracking of the problems and allows creating separate tickets within SE's tracking system. With them all in one question, it's a jumbled mess for tracking the issues from creation through resolution.

For #2, (from memory) there's a mode switch toggle in the top-right corner of the editor frame which should show 3 options. One of those options is Markdown with preview. IIRC, it's the option on the right. In Teams, that option is not displayed.
